# MySQL Workbench couldnt set new date type for "DATE"

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a problem with mysql workbench - for some reason it doesn't allow me to set 'DATE' as datatype any record. I'm a total beginner if it comes to mysql but i'm forced to use this program (school relevent). I hope any one of you may be able to help me with this. I uploaded a screenshot with the error.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before setting  DATE to not NULL put in default column 0000-00-00

EDIT:

```
UPDATE `Reparatie`
SET `Datum_reparatie_invoer` = str_to_date( `Datum_reparatie_invoer`, '%Y-%m-%d' );
```

Do the same for the other column.

Comment: hi, i already put the correct synthax for DATE in the inserts "2005-05-05" etc. but for some reason it just doesn't allow me to change the datetype to DATE nor does it show up if i click to show me the list for all datatypes - however it does allow me to change it to DATETIME, but thats not what i want

Comment: Post the table schema.